# Visual Studio 2010 MSI project and Service Installer Class using Custom Actions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-services, installation, windows-installer

Other than this, my installer class is nothing special.  It installs the windows service.  But now I am needing to prompt the user for some info and pass the info to the installer class so that the installer class can update the app.config.

I added three extra pages to the default User Interface:

- Textboxes (A)
- Textboxes (B)
- Textboxes (C)

Variables:

- On A, I am using EDITA1, and the rest are invisible
- On B, I am using EDITB1, and the rest are invisible
- On C, I am using EDITC1, and the rest are invisible

In the "Install" Custom Action, I have the Properties set like this:

- Arguments: Blank
- Condition: Blank
- CustomActionData: /MYPARAM1=[EDITA1] /MYPARAM2=[EDITB1] /MYPARAM3=[EDITC1]
- InstallerClass: True

In the installer class, Install is overridden

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    base.Install(stateSaver);    

    // This is to display the Parameters
    // It comes up blank.  No Parameters.
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    foreach (string s in Context.Parameters.Keys)
    {
        sb.Append(s);
        sb.Append(":");
        sb.AppendLine(Context.Parameters[s]);
    }
    //throw new InstallException(sb.ToString());

    //This returns TRUE.
    //throw new InstallException(Context.Parameters.ContainsKey("MYPARAM1").ToString());

    string x= Context.Parameters["MYPARAM1"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
    {
        throw new InstallException("Missing parameter 'MYPARAM1'");
    }

    <snip>
}
```

When the app runs, MYPARAM1 is empty, so I see the InstallException at the end.

I added two chunks of test code at the top of install.  The first, creates a string with all the params that should have come in on the command line.  I do not get my parameters at all.  The second chunk reports "TRUE" -- meaning that the key "MYPARAM1" was on the command line.  The first and second chunk do not agree.  How can this be?

As an experiment, I tried changing the strings to /MYPARAM1 instead of MYPARAM1.  That did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step would be to create a verbose log to see the full command line passed to your custom action. Command to create log: `msiexec /i "C:\MyPackage\Example.msi" /L*V "C:\log\example.log"`

In the log you can search for the property names to see they get set correctly and also are being passed to your custom action.

Comment: Thanks!  I found the problem like this.